# How to run RTerm.exe on background (Running a custom GUI)

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a custom GUI for R using gWidgets, I've stumbled on this thread: [Running an R script using a Windows shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312417/running-an-r-script-using-a-windows-shortcut),
which helped me a lot, but theres only one issue left: the black command prompt of the RTerm still appears. How can I make it invisible? is there an option for this? What I got so far was the --silent option.

Comment: Good question. I wonder how other user interfaces -- ESS on Emacs, Rstudio, Rcommander, Revolutions R,  do this. Do they use Rterm.exe or R.exe in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Rscript.exe` instead of `Rterm.exe`, then see the following post: [How to wait for a keypress in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272916/how-to-wait-for-a-keypress-in-r/15283106#15283106).