# Getting R Plots into a Separate Non-R Window

Tags: r, plot, window

Is there any way to get R plots to pop-up in a separate window outside of RGui?

x11() does this in RStudio but not in RGui.

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to -1 the question please let me know why, I don't want to waste anyone's time with inefficient questions in the future.

Comment: this question is a bit OffTopic here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run a Cairo device from the cairoDevice package then the graph shows up in a separate window (at least my test on windows did).

If you run Rgui (on windows) in SDI mode instead of MDI mode then the standard graphics device will be a different window from the command line (but scripts, help, etc. will be as well).

The tkrplot package has tools for creating graphs in a separate Tk window.

You could send the graph to a file, then use `shell.exec` to open the viewer for the graphics file in a separate window.

There may be other ways as well.

Comment: Awesome I'll give those a shot. Thanks for your answer here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312417/running-an-r-script-using-a-windows-shortcut

Comment: I ended up using SDI mode vs MDI mode, worked just fine.